# "Your sandbox app details could not be fetched."

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'am new to the paypal (rest) api but got a simple example to work in the sandbox. Now today it suddenly stopped working, throwing a

> 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

And at least I am not aware (neither is git!) of ANY code changes.

Now I'm logged into the paypal developer dashboard and in the section "My Apps & Credentials" scrolled down to "REST API apps" where I have one app called "test". When I click on it to see the details it says:

> Something went wrong. Your sandbox app details could not be fetched.
>   You can try again or you can fetch your live app details.

I can create new apps but with their credentials it also ends up in the 401. I tried to delete the test app but it says

> Application test could not be deleted

Can anybody explain this to me an then maybe lead me to a understandable tutorial on how to go live? The resources provided by paypal really confuse me.

Comment: "The resources provided by paypal really confuse me." if it makes you feel any better it's not only you! - I can just add 401 is for authentication errors as PayPal [says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/errors/#authentication-errors) please make sure "that the access token is valid and present and not expired."

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new sandbox business US account and retry again?

In the developer portal, can you check if the sandbox account is successfully created or is it showing an error "Something when wrong..."?
You may check this by clicking Profile tab under the sandbox email in developer portal.